# AngularJs website templates not opening in Internet Explorer

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, safari

When I open my angularjs website in Internet Explorer it gives some warnings (HTML 1300 Navigation occured) and errors somecontroller got undefined. Website is working fine with Chrome and Firefox. Just problem with IE and Safari

**Code Sample**

```
 $scope.loadMoreSubCat = function (pageno = 2) {
      blockUI.stop();
      $http.get(apiURL).success(function (data) {
        $http.get(apiURL).success(function (data) {
          if (data.length) {
            angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
              $scope.listings.push(value);
            });
            $scope.busy = false;
          } else {
            $scope.busy = true;
            $('#status').html('No More Listings');
          }
        }).error(function (err) {
          $('#status').html('No More Listings');
        });
        pageno++;
        $rootScope.pageno = pageno;
      }
    }
```

Comment: hi, can you please post your code and full error message with the question??

Comment: Hi,I figured out the error but doesn't understand why its happening. Here is my Controller function and it gives me error  on my function parameter i.e. pageno=2. it says unexpected ')',

Comment: $scope.loadMoreSubCat = function( pageno =2) {blockUI.stop();     $http.get(apiURL).success(function(data) {$http.get(apiURL).success(function(data) {if(data.length) { angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
   $scope.listings.push(value);  
                    });$scope.busy = false; } else {
                     $scope.busy = true; 
                    $('#status').html('No More Listings');
                  } }).error(function(err) { 
                $('#status').html('No More Listings'); });  pageno++;   
              $rootScope.pageno=pageno;};

Comment: I've posted an answer but you should update the question to include the function and error-msg.

Comment: Hi gaurav As @DanielBornstrand pointed out this feature is not there in IE you can use the workaround i have provided also i have updated the question with sample you pasted in the comment section. Please include the full code sample and the exact error message in the future questions

Answer (score 0):

You are using the ES6 feature "default parameters", which is not implemented in IE.

```
function( pageno =2) {}
```

https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

You can use a transpiler like babel to translate ES6 code to ES5. Or just avoid using ES6 features.

Answer (score 0):

Default parameters are not widely supported in all browsers. IE does not support this feature, i would suggest the following workaround for IE

```
function(pageno) {
 if(!pageno){
   pageno = 2;
 }
}
```

[image]

For more info
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters